# Как ускорить скрипт?

Tags: python, алгоритм, генераторы

При прохождение теста, 1 из тестов не срабатывает из за превышение лимита, либо ошибки в коде.

> Суть задания если в нижней строке из файла text.txt (1 7 3 4 7 9) есть
>   сумма из двух чисел равная значению верхней (5), то в файл записать 1,
>   иначе 0.

```
    import os
    def main():
        f = open('text.txt', 'r').read().split()
        w = open('text2.txt', 'r+')
        target = int(f[0])
        l = [int(f[i]) for i in range(1, len(f))]
        l.sort()
        print(l)
        # Как ускорить данный участок кода
        for i in range(len(l)):
            for j in range(len(l) - 1):
                if l[i] + l[j + 1] == target:
                    w.write('1')
                    return
        #
        if os.stat('text2.txt').st_size == 0:
            w.write('0')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

````
Содержание файла text.txt:

```
5
1 7 3 4 7 9
```
````

> Воспользовался всеми советами, в итоге на 1 тест прошел больше, но другой тест так же выходит за заданное время в 1 сек (1.091s). К сожалению, нет примерных данных с того теста. Спасиб всем кто помог с поиском решения.

```
    import itertools

    def fun(target, nums):
        for x in nums[:-1]:
            for y in nums[x+1:] :
                if x+y == target :
                    return True
        return False

    def main():
        with open('text.txt') as f:
            target, l = f.readlines()
        target = int(target)
        l = [int(i) for i in l.split() if target >= int(i)]
        l.sort()
        print(l)

        flag = fun(target, l)

        with open('text2.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('1' if flag else '0')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Для оформления кода нужно использовать не апострофы `'''`, а `\`\`\``. Либо в редакторе используйте кнопку `{}`, она добавит слева отступ в 3 пробела (`   `), что укажет редактору на оформление текста как код

Comment: скорее всего ошибка тут "if l[i] + l[j + 1] == target:", так как вы обращаетесь к элементу за пределами его диапазона.собственно сам код не дописан нет логики для записи 1 и 0

Comment: Выкиньте itertools, выкиньте sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо двойного цикла можно использовать [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), скорость работы увеличится на ~40%

Пример теста скорости:

```
import itertools

def has_1(target: int, nums: list) -> bool:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[i] + nums[j + 1] == target:
                return True

    return False

def has_2(target: int, nums: list) -> bool:
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(nums, 2):
        if a + b == target:
            return True

    return False

target = 5
nums = [1, 3, 4, 7, 7, 9]

import timeit
print(
    timeit.timeit('has_1(target, nums)', globals=globals())
)
# 0.7132318

print(
    timeit.timeit('has_2(target, nums)', globals=globals())
)
# 0.3819617999999999
```

---

**PS.**

Использование `itertools` в коде из вопроса с небольшим рефакторингом:

```
import itertools

def main():
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        target, nums = f.readlines()

    target = int(target)
    nums = [int(i) for i in nums.split()]
    nums.sort()

    result = False
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(nums, 2):
        if a + b == target:
            result = True
            break

    with open('text2.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('1' if result else '0')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: кстати, если сортируете, выкиньте те, что больше или равны target - для олимпиады может быть важно. Да и itertools не дает такой уж выгоды - я ниже в ответ ванильный питон положил

Answer (score 3):

на 20 % быстрее ответа @gil9red  :) на моем ноуте timeit дает (последний код ниже)

```
1.1719330577166354
0.6272641881987562
0.5278181732993907


def f( target, nums ):
    for x in nums[:-1]:
        for y in nums[x+1:] :
            if x+y == target :
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Действительно, быстрее :) Круто :)

Comment: Возможно, на длинных списках, можно немного ещё ускориться, добавив if x >= target: continue

Comment: Если среди чисел не будут 0 и меньше :)

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить про скорость.

Соберите все свои единички-нолики в единую строку,
а после окончания цикла запишите эту строку в файл одной-единственной операцией.

А вот что такое "верхняя" и "Нижняя" строка - непонятно.

Кстати, вот это условие - "сумма из двух чисел равная значению верхней (5), то в файл записать 1, **иначе 0**." у вас вообще никак не отрабатывается.

Так что исправляйте проблемы с логикой, потом - со скоростью -  потом будем смотреть дальше.

P.S. Даже после ваших корректировок ваш код не соответствует заданию в тойт формулировке, которую вы-же и привели.

Comment: из списка [1, 7, 3, 4, 7, 9], сумма 1 и 4 даст 5 т.е target. Дальше произойдет запись 1 в текстовый документ и программа закончит свое выполнение, в случае если  4 заменить на 0, то после прохода по всем итерациям пройдет проверку на значение в файле (в данном случае на наличие символов) и запишит 0 в текстовый файл.